# Segfault with lcms2 ctypes binding and threads

Tags: python, multithreading, ctypes

First of all, excuse me if it's been anwered before... I'm pretty good at finding informations but since my programming skills are rather basic I might not have understood what was there...

I'm trying to do color conversions with Python. I used to use the Python bindings of lcms1 but since there are no official bindings for lcms2 I tried my luck with ctypes and ctypesgen.
I used `ctypesgen.py -llcms2 /usr/include/lcms2.h /usr/include/lcms2_plugin.h -o lcms2.py` and deleted all `.value()` as it wouldn't work otherwise.

It all works beautifully (for my rather simple needs) except when threads are involved...
Here is a sample code:

```
from multiprocessing.dummy import Pool 
from lcms2 import *

DblTriplet = c_double * 3

def Lab2RGB(values):
    context = cmsCreateContext(None, None)
    inprof = cmsCreateLab4ProfileTHR(context, None)
    outprof = cmsCreate_sRGBProfileTHR(context)
    inbuf = DblTriplet(*values)
    outbuf = DblTriplet()
    xform = cmsCreateTransformTHR(context, inprof, TYPE_Lab_DBL, 
                               outprof, TYPE_RGB_DBL,
                               INTENT_PERCEPTUAL, 0)

    cmsCloseProfile(inprof)
    cmsCloseProfile(outprof)

    cmsDoTransform(xform, byref(inbuf), byref(outbuf), 1)
    cmsDeleteTransform(xform)
    cmsDeleteContext(context)

    return tuple(outbuf)

Lab = ((88.98,-1.31,110.87),
       (87.55,2.18,109.06),
       (60.81,65.68,85.06),
       (58.66,70.05,51.19),
       (55.26,72.14,43.46),
       (43.8,79.35,12.7),
       (51.55,78.77,-13.89),
       (47.52,68.9,-42.48),
       (18.74,54.58,-69.51),
       (17.5,42.9,-76.01),
       (14.92,31.84,-67.1),
       (47.57,-33.39,-53.38),
       (57.74,-77.16,0.18),
       (17.06,1.29,2.54),
       )

pool = Pool()
pool.map(Lab2RGB, Lab)
pool.close() 
pool.join()
```

I actually use this in a PyQt app so I'm using QThread but it crashes with Python threads as well. I also used `threading` but finished with `multiprocessing.dummy` in order to easily compare with `multiprocessing`. I also tried the "non THR" lcms2 functions, same problem. I tried `ctypesgen` as well as `h2py`.

So my question is: is there anything wrong in my threading implementation? I read you'd have to take care with ctypes and threads but didn't manage to understand what I could do...

I tried `valgrind python thatscript.py` but that guy speaks way above my head, but strangely it doesn't segfault...

Comment: [cffi](https://cffi.readthedocs.org/en/latest) may be easier for you. It's actively maintained, which can't be said for ctypesgen.